# Spark: Prevent shuffle/exchange when joining two identically partitioned dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` and I want to join these tables many times on a high cardinality field called `visitor_id`.  I would like to perform only one initial shuffle and have all the joins take place without shuffling/exchanging data between spark executors.

To do so, I have created another column called `visitor_partition` that consistently assigns each visitor_id a random value between `[0, 1000)`.  I have used a custom partitioner to ensure that the `df1` and `df2` are exactly partitioned such that each partition contains exclusively rows from one value of `visitor_partition`.  This initial repartition is the only time I want to shuffle the data.

I have saved each dataframe to parquet in s3, paritioning by visitor partition -- for each data frame, this creates 1000 files organized in `df1/visitor_partition=0`, `df1/visitor_partition=1`...`df1/visitor_partition=999`.

Now I load each dataframe from the parquet and register them as tempviews via `df1.createOrReplaceTempView('df1')` (and the same thing for df2) and then run the following query

```
SELECT
   ...
FROM
  df1 FULL JOIN df1 ON
    df1.visitor_partition = df2.visitor_partition AND
    df1.visitor_id = df2.visitor_id
```

In theory, the query execution planner should realize that no shuffling is necessary here.  E.g., a single executor could load in data from `df1/visitor_partition=1` and `df2/visitor_partition=2` and join the rows in there.  However, in practice spark 2.4.4's query planner performs a full data shuffle here.

Is there some way I can prevent this shuffle from taking place?

Comment: did you try performing repartition of each dataset before join and specifying the number of partitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [bucketBy](https://databricks.com/session/bucketing-in-spark-sql-2-3) method of the DataFrameWriter ([other documentation](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-bucketing.html)).

In the following example, the value of the column VisitorID will be hashed into 500 buckets. Normally, for the join Spark would perform an exchange phase based on the hash on the VisitorID. However, in this case you already have the data pre-partitioned with the hash.

```
inputRdd = sc.parallelize(list((i, i%200) for i in range(0,1000000)))

schema = StructType([StructField("VisitorID", IntegerType(), True),
                    StructField("visitor_partition", IntegerType(), True)])

inputdf = inputRdd.toDF(schema)

inputdf.write.bucketBy(500, "VisitorID").saveAsTable("bucketed_table")

inputDf1 = spark.sql("select * from bucketed_table")
inputDf2 = spark.sql("select * from bucketed_table")
inputDf3 = inputDf1.alias("df1").join(inputDf2.alias("df2"), col("df1.VisitorID") == col("df2.VisitorID"))
```

Sometimes Spark query optimizer still choose broadcast exchange, so for our example, let's disable auto broadcasting

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
```

The physical plan would look as follow:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) SortMergeJoin [VisitorID#351], [VisitorID#357], Inner
:- *(1) Sort [VisitorID#351 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- *(1) Project [VisitorID#351, visitor_partition#352]
:     +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(VisitorID#351)
:        +- *(1) FileScan parquet default.bucketed_6[VisitorID#351,visitor_partition#352] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(VisitorID#351)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/bucketed_6], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(VisitorID)], ReadSchema: struct<VisitorID:int,visitor_partition:int>, SelectedBucketsCount: 500 out of 500
+- *(2) Sort [VisitorID#357 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- *(2) Project [VisitorID#357, visitor_partition#358]
      +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(VisitorID#357)
         +- *(2) FileScan parquet default.bucketed_6[VisitorID#357,visitor_partition#358] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(VisitorID#357)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/bucketed_6], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(VisitorID)], ReadSchema: struct<VisitorID:int,visitor_partition:int>, SelectedBucketsCount: 500 out of 500
```

Doing something like:

```
inputdf.write.partitionBy("visitor_partition").saveAsTable("partitionBy_2")
```

Creates indeed the structure with a folder for each partition. But it's not working since the Spark join is based on the hash and is not able to leverage your custom structure.

Edit: I misunderstood your example. I believe you were talking about something like partitionBy, not repartition as mentioned in the previous version.

Comment: I would also go with the bucketing technique.