# How to efficiently join a very large table and a large table in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have two tables. Both the tables are external tables in hive stored in parquet data format.

The first table **table_1** has **250 Million** rows on daily basis from year 2015. This table is partitioned based on create_date. So for every create_date, there is about 250M rows.

The second table - **table_2** is daily delta table and the average row count is about **1.5 Million** rows.

There is one common column **"lookup_id"** in both tables. Now I need to fetch all the columns from table_1 for the delta data from table_2 using data frames.

I thought of doing something like below

```
table_1=spark.table("table_1")
table_2=spark.table("table_2")
result_df=table_1.join(table_2, table_1.lookup_id=table_2.lookup_id, "inner").drop(table_2.lookup_id)
```

But I doubt if this is really efficient and if pyspark will be able to handle this without any memory errors.

**Question 1:**
How to parallelize the table_1 scan based on create_date partitions?

**Question 2:**
Is there any other way to optimize table_1 scan based on the lookup_ids from table_2 and/or based on partitions?

**Additional info to give more clarity on what I am looking for:**

I am trying to understand when we join the tables using dataframes, does spark read the data and keep it in memory and join them or it just joins while reading itself. If the second one is true, what are all the joins the second statement is applicable for. Also if there is any need to use loop to avoid any memory errors.

Comment: Is there any relation between `table1.create_date` and `table2.create_date` ? For example, is this true that if `row1.lookup_id == row2.lookup_id` then `row1.create_date == row2.create_date` for row1 ∈ table1 and row2 ∈ table2 ?

Comment: No, only lookup_id is available. create_date is not available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about your driver and executor  memory, but in general two possible join optimizations are - broadcasting the small table to all executors and having the same partition key for both the dataframes. In your case repartitioning based on your lookup id will make it faster if table 2 is too huge to be broadcasted. But reparationing has its own cost.  You can find more here - [https://umbertogriffo.gitbook.io/apache-spark-best-practices-and-tuning/avoiding_shuffle_less_stage-_more_fast#:~:text=One%20way%20to%20avoid%20shuffles,then%20broadcast%20to%20every%20executor](https://umbertogriffo.gitbook.io/apache-spark-best-practices-and-tuning/avoiding_shuffle_less_stage-_more_fast#:%7E:text=One%20way%20to%20avoid%20shuffles,then%20broadcast%20to%20every%20executor).

Let me know what you think. looking forward to a discussion in this topic.

If you cannot broadcast,an example of avoiding join using bucketing - inspired from here : [Spark: Prevent shuffle/exchange when joining two identically partitioned dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59034719/spark-prevent-shuffle-exchange-when-joining-two-identically-partitioned-datafra)

```
spark.catalog.setCurrentDatabase(<your databasename>)
test1.write.mode('overwrite').bucketBy(100,'item').saveAsTable('table_item')
test2.write.mode('overwrite').bucketBy(100,'item').saveAsTable('table_item1')
#test1.

#%%
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1) # this is just to disable auto broadcasting for testing
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
inputDf1 = spark.sql("select * from table_item")
inputDf2 = spark.sql("select * from table_item1")
inputDf3 = inputDf1.alias("df1").join(inputDf2.alias("df2"),on='item')
```

Now try

```
inputDf3.explain()
```

The result will be something like this:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) Project [item#1033, col1#1030, col2#1031, col3#1032, id#1038]
+- *(3) SortMergeJoin [item#1033], [item#1039], Inner
   :- *(1) Sort [item#1033 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- *(1) Project [col1#1030, col2#1031, col3#1032, item#1033]
   :     +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(item#1033)
   :        +- *(1) FileScan parquet 
   +- *(2) Sort [item#1039 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- *(2) Project [id#1038, item#1039]
         +- *(2) Filter isnotnull(item#1039)
            +- *(2) FileScan parquet
```

As you can see there is no Exchange hashpartitioning happening here. So try bucketing both of your dataframe and try to join.

Comment: thanks for sharing the page. Very useful content. Thanks for pointing out the broadcast operation. Rather than joining both the tables at once, I am thinking of broadcasting only the lookup_id from table_2  and perform the table scan. Then I will join table_2 to again to take the necessary columns. However, I am not sure if broadcast join (or any join) would take only the data that satisfies the join condition. 

I am also searching if there is a way to use the partition field to parallelize the table scan operation.

Comment: I think spark is intelligent enough to manage the parallelization of your joins based on the maximum number of executors that you allot. So you just need to broadcast table 2 to all partitions and do the join. This will avoid the shuffle and the filtering and join will be efficient. If it helps, consider upvoting and accepting the answer.

Comment: Instead of reading the whole data first and doing a join, if I loop through the individual create_dates on table_1 and try to join, will it be any faster as the first table is partitioned based on create date?

Comment: I dont think so because the shuffle is going to happen anyways. dividing into smaller jobs work when there is no memory to handle task, but it will not fasten the process . Because at the end you have to union them and thats a cost too even though there is no shuffle. on the other hand if you join by the partition key, then there is no shuffling and that will fasten the process.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not bring create_date from the second table as it has to be looked up from table_1. I can not partition on id as there are other queries that uses partition join based on create date. If the data is clustered based on lookup_id on both the tables, do you think shuffling and sorting will happen?

Comment: if both the tables are repartitioned based on look up id, i dont think the shuffle will happen. Because spark partitioning is has partition and same values will end up in same partition i guess.

Comment: I mean to ask if the shuffle will happen if the lookup_id is bucketed on both table_1 and table_2. 
The table_1 partition will still be create_date but under create_date partition, data will be bucketed based on lookup_id

Comment: Found something interesting - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59034719/spark-prevent-shuffle-exchange-when-joining-two-identically-partitioned-datafra
So as per here, repartition or partitionBy cannot avoid shuffling. only bucketing will do this. I tried this and  i find it true from my physical plan.  so in your case bucket both your tables based on lookupid and join it. check your physical plan - it should not show "Exchange hashpartitioning" . Also see the updated code in my answer

Comment: Interesting! let me try both with partitioning and bucketing separately on some test tables to see which one works best. thanks for your help. Please consider reformatting your answer based on your recent findings for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

When you will read the CSV .. it will be automatically partitioned and parallel processing will happen .. based on the default configuration (in case we aren't changing any)

A specific answer to this ...If you have a 30GB uncompressed text file stored on HDFS, then with the default HDFS block size setting (128MB) it would be stored in 235 blocks, which means that the RDD you read from this file would have 235 partitions.

Now, There's two things here **1. Flat files like CSV and 2. compressed file like parquet**

1. When you have a text file ...When Spark reads a file from HDFS, it creates a single partition for a single input split. Input split is set by the Hadoop InputFormat used to read this file. For instance, if you use textFile() it would be TextInputFormat in Hadoop, which would return you a single partition for a single block of HDFS (but the split between partitions would be done on line split, not the exact block split), unless you have a compressed text file.
2. For a parquet or compressed file : In case of compressed file you would get a single partition for a single file (as compressed text files are not splittable).

Now, as you are using parquet this is already well partitioned, while doing optimization , you can check your cluster size and see how much partitions happened etc.

So, answer : **Question 1: How to parallelize the table_1 scan based on create_date partitions?** This is already partitioned

For , **Question 2: Is there any other way to optimize table_1 scan based on the lookup_ids from table_2 and/or based on partitions?**

You can try filtering the records which are not necessary , this concept is called Spark predicate push down in Spark SQL queries, so even before loading the data into memory spark will filter out unnecessary columns .. more [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkPredicatePushdown.html#:%7E:text=Spark%20SQL%20queries-,Spark%20predicate%20push%20down%20to%20database%20allows%20for%20better%20optimized,located%20in%20the%20WHERE%20clause.)

> Spark predicate push down to database allows for better optimized
> Spark queries. A predicate is a condition on a query that returns true
> or false, typically located in the WHERE clause. A predicate push down
> filters the data in the database query, reducing the number of entries
> retrieved from the database and improving query performance. By
> default the Spark Dataset API will automatically push down valid WHERE
> clauses to the database.

Comment: thanks for your response. I can not use PPD as the second table is already delta table ans so all the filters are already applied before loading this table. I need to lookup for all the lookup id from delta table. 
What I am unclear on is, when I run the steps I have given in my question, will spark read the table first and do the join in spark memory? or will it try to join while reading itself?  If it will try to join while reading itself, is this applicable for all joins?  or specific to any joins?

Comment: It's actually not like that, based on the filter given , the data will be sent to executor  or the executor will read those data only, now all this join , count() - this are the transformation in spark, so a logical plan will be created first , post that , a final physical plan will be created an a DAG lineage will be developed, so you can say, filter will happen first then the transformation ; Hope this will bring clarity .

Comment: So if the data is read first, the data is copied into dataframes and then join happens. Indirectly I am looking for a way to do a predicate push down using second table lookup_id but that the second table is also having 1.5M million rows. So I am wondering if broadcast join will help spark to filter the data while reading itself. 
My cluster has limited capacity so I can not go for more executor memory at the same time I want the join to be performed efficiently

Comment: Mohan - The broadcast join will not help you to filter down data, Broadcast join helps in reducing network call by sending the dataset/making available the dataset which you are broadcasting to every executor/node in your cluster. Also, 1.5 million in big data space is not a much load to play around :) Hope this helps ..

Comment: Great, that it helped you  would appreciate if you could upvote  meanwhile